# IHttpClientFactory reads the data through the web api, the object type becomes ValueKind = Number？

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

Services for obtaining data:

```
   return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Output>>(
                await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"api/varValueLists"),
                new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
                });
```

blazorh background reading：

```
 var _lists= await ModbusService.ModbusGetListAsync();
```

In the Output entity, Value is of object type：

```
public  class Output
    {
        public string VarName { get; set; }
       
        public string Address { get; set; }
        
        public byte StationNumber { get; set; }
        
        public byte FunctionCode { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

here it should be float becomes like this
[image]

When Value is of type bool, it is also such a value:

> Value = ValueKind = True: "True"

Comment: In JSON, there's just "Number", there's no distinction between integers and floating-point numbers - because you've used `object`, that's what you get. Why don't you just make your class `float Value` instead of `object Value`?

Comment: Because when reading variables, I need to distinguish data types. For example, bool is the switch state of some devices. Modifying this type will involve a lot of code modifications.
Using json, how can I convert the obtained data to the original bool, float, that is, the original entity class cannot be modified, thank you

Comment: Short answer: you can't really. JSON only understands "numbers", so you're going to lose fidelity when it's transmitted over the wire. The deserializer can only tell you the type based on what's supported by JSON, which would be object, array, boolean, number, string.

Comment: Understand, according to what you said, refactored the code, thank you